# Can I use Seriously.js on a p5.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I am trying to use [Seriously.js](https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js) with a canvas as its source (as opposed to an image), specifically a p5.js canvas. In its README, Seriously.js states

> Accept image input from varied sources: video, image, canvas, array, webcam, Three.js

However, I have not managed to get a canvas as the source to work.

What I tried: I took [this live example](https://brianchirls.github.io/Seriously.js/examples/blur/directionblur.html) and modified it to use a canvas instead of the image (and getting rid of the `require.js` thing). As soon as I switch from the image to the p5.js canvas it does not work anymore. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Seriously.js Directional Motion Blur Example</title>

  <script src="libraries/seriously.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/effects/seriously.directionblur.js"></script>

  <script src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

    #controls {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    #controls input {
      width: 400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="619"></canvas>
  <div id="controls">
    <div><label for="amount">Blur</label><input type="range" id="amount" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" value="0.1"/></div>
    <div><label for="angle">Angle</label><input type="range" id="angle" min="0" max="6.2831853072" step="0.001" value="0"/></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var seriously = new Seriously();

      var target = seriously.target('#canvas');
      var moblur = seriously.effect('directionblur');
      moblur.source = seriously.source('#p5sourceCanvas');

      moblur.amount = '#amount';
      moblur.angle = '#angle';

      target.source = moblur;
      seriously.go();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(In the `sketch.js` I made sure that the canvas has the id of `p5sourceCanvas`).

When I run this, the console gives me the following error:

```
seriously.js:3331 Uncaught Error: Unknown source type
```

(for convenience [here](https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/blob/master/seriously.js#L3331) is the line in the Seriously.js source code)

I also tried the same with a `canvas` element that I simply created via HTML, it gives the same error.

So, my question: Is there any way to get this to work on a p5.js canvas? Or am I misunderstanding the term canvas in the docs? Or is it a bug?

Edit: For further clarification here is the entire p5.js sketch.

```
function setup() {
  sourceCanvas = createCanvas(640, 619);
  sourceCanvas.id('p5sourceCanvas');
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(random(width), random(height), 40, 40);
}
```

Comment: P5 code is most likeky ran at page's load event or alike (otherwise it couldn't append to the doc), so at the time you call seriously, `#p5sourceCanvas` is null.

Comment: Looking at the minified p5.js source code there is one canvas from which a webGL context is attained. This canvas is conditionally appended to the DOM with the id `defaultCanvas0` (or the zero is a higher number if that id is already used) so try `moblur.source = seriously.source('#defaultCanvas0'); ` after P5 has been instanced or if you are instantiating P5 yourself then use the P5 object to get the canvas. Eg `const myP5 = new P5(); moblur.source = seriously.source(myP5.canvas /* or "#"+myP5.canvas.id */);` Though without a full example there is not much else I can do.

Comment: @Blindman67 you can define a custom id for the canvas element with the [`id` method](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/id). OP probably did it in the `sketch.js` file. But anyway, the problem is obviously that they don't wait for p5 to be initialized before calling Seriously. Since p5 code is in the head, there is no way* it can append its elements in the body before Seriously's code is called. *(\* well except if p5 was using MutationObservers, but they don't).*

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, but how can I wait for p5 to be initialized before calling seriously? Just moving it down in the body, before the script does not work. Is there any other way, I could make sure it is initialized. Also, what about my observation that a regular HTML canvas also does not work? I did try it again with a simple HTML canvas with red background color and it does not render any output canvas (although it does *not* give the same error message in the console).

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', seriouslyCode)` should do it.

Comment: jsfiddle wraps the *script* part autmatically in a  load handler, and it works : https://jsfiddle.net/w91um5a2/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks a lot, that makes it work. However, apparently it only blurs (and then freezes) the first frame. Do you happen to know why that is and if there is a way to redraw the sketch and apply the Seriously.js code on each redrawn frame? Also, do you want to turn your comment into a proper answer, then I can upvote and accept it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, but you will have to execute your Seriously code only after the p5.js one has executed.
It seems that p5 fires in DOMContentLoaded, so if you wait until the window's load event, you should be fine.

Also, while I don't really know Seriously.js, it seems that you need to call the canvas Seriously#`source`'s `update()` in order for Seriously to know it has to re-render it. One way to do so, is to attach a property to your CanvasElement, that you will try to call from within the p5 `draw` loop :

```js
 function apply() {
   // declare our variables
   var seriously, // the main object that holds the entire composition
    moblur,
    target; // a wrapper object for our target canvas

   seriously = new Seriously();
   target = seriously.target('#canvas');
   moblur = seriously.effect('directionblur');
      // attach it to the DOM element
   moblur.source = p5sourceCanvas._seriouslyObj = seriously.source('#p5sourceCanvas');

   moblur.amount = '#amount';
   moblur.angle = '#angle';

   target.source = moblur;
   seriously.go();
  }
// only when the page has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', apply);
```

```css
 img {
   display: none;
  }

  #controls {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
  }

  #controls input {
   width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/513d2b86/seriously.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/513d2b86/effects/seriously.directionblur.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="619"></canvas>
 <div id="controls">
  <div><label for="amount">Blur</label><input type="range" id="amount" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" value="0.05"/></div>
  <div><label for="angle">Angle</label><input type="range" id="angle" min="0" max="6.2831853072" step="0.001" value="0"/></div>
 </div>
  <script>function setup() {
  sourceCanvas = createCanvas(640, 619);
  sourceCanvas.id('p5sourceCanvas');
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(random(width), random(height), 40, 40);
  // if seriously has been attached, call its update method
  sourceCanvas.elt._seriouslyObj && sourceCanvas.elt._seriouslyObj.update();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is so great, works perfectly. Wish, I could upvote twice. Thank you so much for taking the time to help a beginner!